# Selenium python for click and select value from draw down list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

HTML for the website:

```
<div data-v-c9f77e09="">
  User Category：
  <div data-v-c9f77e09="" class="el-select" style="width: 200px">
    <div class="select-trigger el-tooltip__trigger el-tooltip__trigger">
      <!--v-if--><!-- fix: https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/issues/11415 --><!--v-if-->
      <div class="el-input el-input--suffix">
        <!-- input --><!-- prepend slot --><!--v-if-->
        <div class="el-input__wrapper" tabindex="-1">
          <!-- prefix slot --><!--v-if--><input
            class="el-input__inner"
            type="text"
            readonly=""
            autocomplete="off"
            tabindex="0"
            placeholder="Select"
            id="el-id-8303-7"
          /><!-- suffix slot --><span class="el-input__suffix"
            ><span class="el-input__suffix-inner"
              ><i class="el-icon el-select__caret el-select__icon"
                ><svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
                >
                  <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M831.872 340.864 512 652.672 192.128 340.864a30.592 30.592 0 0 0-42.752 0 29.12 29.12 0 0 0 0 41.6L489.664 714.24a32 32 0 0 0 44.672 0l340.288-331.712a29.12 29.12 0 0 0 0-41.728 30.592 30.592 0 0 0-42.752 0z"
                  ></path></svg></i
              ><!--v-if--><!--v-if--><!--v-if--><!--v-if--><!--v-if--><!--v-if--></span
            ></span
          >
        </div>
        <!-- append slot --><!--v-if-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my step for Selenium  test:

1. set and click  as drawdown list to open list
2. get the input value by using input.text() method, however, it fails to select the option in the list during the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try Select, maybe it works (I don't know the url link):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
opeion_list = Select(driver.find_element(by='??', value='??')) #locate the slecetable element

for option in opeion_list.options: 
    print(option.text) #There some methods to select an option. If there is no problem, you must see all option as text.

opeion_list.select_by_visible_text(??) #Instead of ?? put the the text you want to select.
```